# Unable to run Form

Tags: c#, forms

I've been coding a Generic Dictionary and have came across a problem when trying to run it.

When I run the Program I get this error: `The type or namespace name 'MainForm' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Here is my Program.cs Code:

```
    namespace CriminalRecords
{
    class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// The main entry point for the application.
            /// </summary>        
            {
                Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
                Application.Run(new MainForm());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The error appears because of MainForm but this is the name of my form.
My question is that what is causing this and how can I fix it?

Comment: what is the namespace under which your `MainFrom` is defined?

Comment: Are they in the same project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program class is defined in the  `CriminalRecords` namespace.  Unless `MainForm` is also part of this namespace, you'll get this error.

You can either add `using NamespaceContainingMainForm;` at the top of your file, or fully qualify the name of `MainForm` with the namespace.

Answer (score 1):

The error : The type or namespace name 'MainForm' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

simply means that it cannot find `MainForm()` class definition.

Either the namespace is different and is not equal to `CriminalRecords` in which you need to import or add this:

```
using projectName.namespaceName
```

where `namespaceName` is the namespace under which `MainForm` is defined.

If your MainForm is in another project, you need to add reference to that project and also add the following:

```
using anotherProjectName.namespace
```